# Angular 2 declare global css or js frameworks

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have a simple question more about best practice/performance.

When you have to include a CSS or Javascript framework (bootstrap, jquery, ...) to your project, do you include them on the index.html or declare it on the .angular-cli.json?

I know that bouth aproaches work, but is there a best practice on this? Is there an advantage of using one or other?

Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to install them using `npm` or `yarn` package managers and then add them to your `.angular-cli.json`

The advantage here is that you just have to look at one place to find all your dependencies, the `package.json` file. You can also easily upgrade to the latest version and the package manager will warn you if the version is not compatible with your other packages.

Comment: I agree. Additionally, concerning performance, if you are using a server that uses HTTP/1, the performance will be less than if you were to include them in `angular-cli.json`. This is because the number of calls to the server will increase if you include libraries in the HTML. If you use the `angular-cli.json`, they will be bundled in the `scripts.bundle.js` file: reducing calls. This does not matter with HTTP 2 though.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Allow me another last question following @Dhyey answer. Is it better to: 1) install a framework, let's say Bootstrap, with npm as a project dependency or 2) to declare it using a CDN?

Comment: @jfpcarreria if u are using http 2 go for the cdn, if u r using http 1 go for npm